# Sorting by text instead of value on select column on a JQGRID

Tags: sorting, select, jqgrid

am using JQGrid and am display a select column.  below is my colmodel

```
{"name":"ID", "index": "ID", "width": "200", "jsonmap": "cell.ID", "editable": false },
{"name":"SalesTypeID","index":"SalesTypeID","width":"200","jsonmap":"cell.SalesTypeID",
"editable":true, "formatter": "select", "edittype": "select", "editoptions": { "value":
"1:N;
 2:C;
 3:R;
 4:R;
 5:I;
 6:I" }}
```

when i try to sort the salestypeid column, it is sorting by key and not by value.  so N appears before C.

how do i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please be a bit more specific? What do you mean when you say "it is sorting by key and not by value".

Comment: in above example, 1 is key and N is value. 2 is key and c is value.  so when i sort it is sorting by key and not value.  hence N comes first and then C comes.  instead C should be first row and then N should come.

Comment: So Id is the key and SalesTypeID is the value? if so client looks okay. Can you put the server side code as well?. Even if you click on the  SalesTypeID column header is it sorting by ID?

Comment: not sure what you mean by server side code?i am loading all the data in above format and trying to do client side sorting.  yes, when i click column header, it is sorting by ID only.